# Custom layout components that are derived from stock components

Tags: android

I want to create a sliding drawer concept for my applications, is there a way to use the Sliding Drawer component as a base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to find the source at the AOSP-repository, but the 1.5 source version can be viewed at Grepcode: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.java/?v=source

Although I haven't tried I think you should be able to use that as a base.